# magento AW_blog tag with a blank link to access 404, how to solve, thank you

Tags: blog

Magento **aw_blog** tag url This link is good,

```
/news/tag/test111/,
```

But such a link

```
(/news/tag/test+111/)
```

Cannot access the page, the system gives 404

Comment: is there any post with the test+111 url?

Comment: https://www.ififa.com/news/?dir=desc&order=created_time&p=5
I checked for a long time. I really did not see where the problem lies. I hope you can help me.

Comment: https://www.ififa.com/news/tag/test111 this is also showing 404 page

Comment: Ififa.com/news/tag/test111, I did not tag in the background, the problem has been solved, thank you very much for your help.
The parameters of the isTagAvailable method under the AW_Blog_Helper_Data class are not urldecode converted